# You can't initialize variables

Tags: swift

Error "Cannot use instance member 'anatherKeyPlistTableData' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" in the last 2 lines

```
var anatherHeaderNameImage: String
var anatherKeyPlistTableData: String

let keyPlistTableDataDefult = "Agregate"
let headerNameImageDefult = "agregate_header"

init(anatherKeyPlistTableData: String?, anatherHeaderNameImage: String?) {
    self.anatherHeaderNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage!
    self.anatherKeyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData!

}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


let keyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData! ?? keyPlistTableDataDefult
let headerNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage! ?? headerNameImageDefult
```

I want to be able to pass values in variables anatherHeaderNameImage and anatherKeyPlistTableData

Answer (score 0):

Even though you wrote those two lines at the bottom of the file, the compiler looks at them right after seeing:

```
var anatherHeaderNameImage: String
var anatherKeyPlistTableData: String

let keyPlistTableDataDefult = "Agregate"
let headerNameImageDefult = "agregate_header"
```

Because they are the top level (not inside a method, for example). At this point, the compiler hasn't even looked at init().

So what you have written doesn't do what you think (if it were legal).  Looking at:

```
let keyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData! ?? keyPlistTableDataDefult
let headerNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage! ?? headerNameImageDefult
```

both "anatherKeyPlistTableData" and "anatherHeaderNameImage" are nil at this point.  (no code has executed).

If they were in viewDidLoad(), for example, they would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your last two lines are two additional properties of your class/struct. It doesn't matter to the compiler that you list them below the initializers, they will always be run before any initializer is run. However, as the property initializers access properties of the instance that is to be initialized but isn't, yet, the Swift compiler complains: before you can use instance members (said properties), the instance has to be fully initialized.

Possible solution #1: make them computed properties:

```
class FooComputedProperties
{
    var anatherHeaderNameImage: String?
    var anatherKeyPlistTableData: String?

    let keyPlistTableDataDefult = "Agregate"
    let headerNameImageDefult = "agregate_header"

    var keyPlistTableData: String { return anatherKeyPlistTableData ?? keyPlistTableDataDefult }
    var headerNameImage: String { return anatherHeaderNameImage ?? headerNameImageDefult }

    init(anatherKeyPlistTableData: String?, anatherHeaderNameImage: String?) {
        self.anatherHeaderNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage
        self.anatherKeyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData

    }
}
```

Possible solution #2: make the defaults `static` (so you can use them in `init`) and initialize the properties:

```
class Foo
{
    var anatherHeaderNameImage: String?
    var anatherKeyPlistTableData: String?

    static let keyPlistTableDataDefult = "Agregate"
    static let headerNameImageDefult = "agregate_header"

    let keyPlistTableData: String
    let headerNameImage: String

    init(anatherKeyPlistTableData: String?, anatherHeaderNameImage: String?) {
        self.anatherHeaderNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage
        self.anatherKeyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData

        self.keyPlistTableData = anatherKeyPlistTableData ?? Foo.keyPlistTableDataDefult
        self.headerNameImage = anatherHeaderNameImage ?? Foo.headerNameImageDefult
    }
}
```

Note that I liberally changed your types and removed forced unwraps so that the nil coalescing operator makes sense.

Also, I left out `init?(coder:)` for brevity.